# R Split a column into multiple column by pattern

Tags: r, split

I want to separate the digits and character in a column of a dataframe `d.df`:

```
col1 
ab 12 14 56
xb 23 234 2342 2
ad 23 45
```

Expected output:

```
col1   col2
ab     12 14 56
xb     23 234 2342 2
ad     23 45
```

I recognize it will be something similar to this, but I'm not sure about the separators

```
t <- as.data.frame(str_match(d$col1,"^(.*)"))
```

I tried many methods and the output was:

```
col1      col2      
a         b 12 14 56
x         b  23 234 2342 2
a         d  23 45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach here will vary significantly depending on whether this is actually how your strings look like or just an example. If they are always two letters and numbers, you can `substring`:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c("ab 12 14 56", "xb 23 234 2342 2", "ad 23 45"))
> 
> df$col1.1 <- sapply(df$col1, substring, 0, 2)
> 
> df$col1.2 <- sapply(df$col1, substring, 3)
> 
> df
              col1 col1.1         col1.2
1      ab 12 14 56     ab       12 14 56
2 xb 23 234 2342 2     xb  23 234 2342 2
3         ad 23 45     ad          23 45
```

If the length and positions of the strings change, regex might be better suited. Using a base R approach, you can extract only the numbers or letters (keeping the white spaces):

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c("ab 12 14 56", "xb 23 234 2342 2", "ad 23 45"))
> df$col1.1 <- sapply(regmatches(df$col1, gregexpr("[a-zA-Z]", df$col1)), paste, collapse = "")
> df$col1.2 <- sapply(regmatches(df$col1, gregexpr("[0-9]\\s*", df$col1)), paste, collapse = "")
> df
              col1 col1.1        col1.2
1      ab 12 14 56     ab      12 14 56
2 xb 23 234 2342 2     xb 23 234 2342 2
3         ad 23 45     ad         23 45
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `separate` from `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
d.df %>% separate(col1, c("col1", "col2"), sep="(?<=[a-z]{2} )")
#   col1           col2
# 1   ab       12 14 56
# 2   xb  23 234 2342 2
# 3   ad          23 45
```

The regex, `"(?<=[a-z]{2} )"`, is a look-behind, meaning "split at the position in the string *after two lower case characters followed by a space*".  `tidyr` seems to have a limit on the length of look-behinds, so `{2}` is used to specify the number of letters.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `data.table`.

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setnames(setDT(df1)[, tstrsplit(col1,
        '(?<=[^0-9]) (?=[0-9])', perl=TRUE)], paste0('col', 1:2))[]
 #   col1          col2
 #1:   ab      12 14 56
 #2:   xb 23 234 2342 2
 #3:   ad         23 45
```

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Using `tstrsplit` from the devel version of 'data.table', split at the space in  'col1' by matching the space after a letter and before a numeric part.  We use regex lookarounds (`(?<=[^0-9])` and (`(?=[0-9])`) for matching.